# android potential bug in edittext?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-drawable

I am not sure if I have a bug inside my head ,or it is inside the android's EditText .

I have a simple EditText .

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name_value"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/feedback_form_comment_box"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:background="@drawable/black_border"
    android:padding="@dimen/feedback_form_padding" />
```

When I run this  , I see a normal edittext with a shapedrawable (just a black border) on the screen. Perfect.

I need to set the gravity now . Because the cursor starts in the middle of the text area. I want the cursor to be displayed in the start of the edittext. So I set the gravity like this .

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/name_value"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/feedback_form_comment_box"
    android:layout_weight="6"
     android:gravity="top|left"
    android:background="@drawable/black_border"
    android:padding="@dimen/feedback_form_padding" />
```

Now mysteriously , the bottom border of the edittext goes away .

This is the shape drawable I am using .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <!--      Solid will define the color of our shape's body -->
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

    <!--  Stroke will define the border of our shape-->
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@color/black" />

</shape>
```

What's going on?

Comment: did you run the app in real device after setting gravity???

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots?

Comment: what is value of this feedback_form_padding ?

Answer (score 0):

bro!
i also come across such a question. It happens on some android pad devices.
After a long test, i find that it was the padding of textview which caused this. Not only the shape drawable but also img background will cause this.

A better way is to set padding for textview manually.

If have time,i will continue to check the source code for what have cause this.